# What exactly is a connection in R?

Tags: r, connection

I've read through and successfully use `?connections` in R but I really don't understand what they are.

I get that I can download a file, read and write a compressed file, ... (*that is I understand what the result of using a conection (open, do stuff, close) but I really don't understand what they actually do, why you have to open and close them and so on*).

I'm hoping this will also help me understand how to more effectively use them (principally understand the mechanics of what is happening so I can effectively debug when something is not working).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Connections were introduced in R 1.2.0 and described by Brian Ripley in the first issue of R NEWS (now called The R Journal) of [January 2001](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-1.pdf) (page 16-17) as an abstracted interface to IO streams such as a file, url, socket, or pipe. In 2013, Simon Urbanek added a [Connections.h](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/include/R_ext/Connections.h) C API which enables R packages to implement custom connection types, such as the [curl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html) package.

One feature of connections is that you can incrementally read or write pieces of data from/to the connection using the `readBin`, `writeBin`, `readLines` and `writeLines` functions. This allows for asynchronous data processing, for example when dealing with large data or network connections:

```
# Read the first 30 lines, 10 lines at a time
con <- url("http://jeroen.github.io/data/diamonds.json") 
open(con, "r")
data1 <- readLines(con, n = 10)
data2 <- readLines(con, n = 10)
data3 <- readLines(con, n = 10)
close(con)
```

Same for writing, e.g. to a file:

```
tmp <- file(tempfile())
open(tmp, "w")
writeLines("A line", tmp)
writeLines("Another line", tmp)
close(tmp)
```

Open the connection as `rb` or `wb` to read/write binary data (called raw vectors in R):

```
# Read the first 3000 bytes, 1000 bytes at a time
con <- url("http://jeroen.github.io/data/diamonds.json") 
open(con, "rb")
data1 <- readBin(con, raw(), n = 1000)
data2 <- readBin(con, raw(), n = 1000)
data3 <- readBin(con, raw(), n = 1000)
close(con)
```

The `pipe()` connection is used to run a system command and pipe text to `stdin` or from `stdout` as you would do with the `|` operator in a shell. E.g. (lets stick with the curl examples), you can run the `curl` command line program and pipe the output to R:

```
con <- pipe("curl -H 'Accept: application/json' https://jeroen.github.io/data/diamonds.json")
open(con, "r")
data1 <- readLines(con, n = 10)
data2 <- readLines(con, n = 10)
data3 <- readLines(con, n = 10)
```

Some aspects of connections are a bit confusing: to incrementally read/write data you need to explicitly `open()` and `close()` the connection. However, `readLines` and `writeLines` automatically open and close (but not destroy!) an unopened connection. As a result, the example below will read the first 10 lines over and over again which is not very useful:

```
con <- url("http://jeroen.github.io/data/diamonds.json") 
data1 <- readLines(con, n = 10)
data2 <- readLines(con, n = 10)
data3 <- readLines(con, n = 10)
identical(data1, data2)
```

Another gotcha is that the C API can both *close* and *destroy* a connection, but R only exposes a function called `close()` **which actually means destroy**. After calling `close()` on a connection it is destroyed and completely useless.

To stream-process data form a connection you want to use a pattern like this:

```
stream <- function(){
  con <- url("http://jeroen.github.io/data/diamonds.json")
  open(con, "r")
  on.exit(close(con))
  while(length(txt <- readLines(con, n = 10))){
    some_callback(txt)
  } 
}
```

The `jsonlite` package relies heavily on connections to import/export [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) data:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(curl)
diamonds <- stream_in(curl("https://jeroen.github.io/data/diamonds.json"))
```

The streaming (by default 1000 lines at a time) makes it fast and memory efficient:

```
library(nycflights13)
stream_out(flights, file(tmp <- tempfile()))
flights2 <- stream_in(file(tmp))
all.equal(flights2, as.data.frame(flights))
```

Finally one nice feature about connections is that the garbage collector will automatically close them if you forget to do so, with an annoying warning:

```
con <- file(system.file("DESCRIPTION"), open = "r")
rm(con)
gc()
```